# In Rsnapshot, error in config excluding remote folders

Tags: linux, rsnapshot

I've severals VPS with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
One of these VPS is the backup master and launches `rsnapshot` to backup its own folders and pull the remote folders on the other VPSs.

These are the commands in the file *rsnapshot.conf*:

```
#server1 (backup server)
backup  /etc/   server1/
backup  /home/  server1/
backup  /opt/   server1/
backup  /root/  server1/
backup  /srv/   server1/
backup  /usr/local/ server1/
backup  /var/   server1/  
exclude /var/cache/
exclude /var/lock/
exclude /var/log/
exclude /var/run/
exclude /var/spool/
exclude /var/tmp/
exclude logs/

 #server2 (remote server)
backup  server2:/etc/   server2/    +rsync_long_args=--rsync-path=/usr/local/bin/rsync_wrapper.sh  
backup  server2:/home/  server2/    +rsync_long_args=--rsync-path=/usr/local/bin/rsync_wrapper.sh  
backup  server2:/opt/   server2/    +rsync_long_args=--rsync-path=/usr/local/bin/rsync_wrapper.sh  
backup  server2:/srv/   server2/    +rsync_long_args=--rsync-path=/usr/local/bin/rsync_wrapper.sh  
backup  server2:/usr/local/ server2/    +rsync_long_args=--rsync-path=/usr/local/bin/rsync_wrapper.sh  
backup  server2:/var/   server2/    +rsync_long_args=--rsync-path=/usr/local/bin/rsync_wrapper.sh,--exclude=/var/cache/,--exclude=/var/lock/,--exclude=/var/log/,--exclude=/var/spool/,--exclude=/var/tmp/
```

With `rsnapshot configtest`, the last row is reported as a configuration error.
My goal is to save the same folders as the main server and to exclude some of them under */var*.

I have consulted the man and several pages online, but I cannot understand what the right syntax is for excluding multiple folders in a single backup row.

Thanks in advance for the help.

---

=== Update ===

I've changed the last command with:

```
backup  server1:/var/   server1/    +rsync_long_args=--rsync-path=/usr/local/bin/rsync_wrapper.sh,exclude_file=/etc/rsnapshot.exclude
```

The file *rsnapshot.exclude* contains:

```
/var/cache/  
/var/lock/  
/var/log/  
/var/run/  
/var/spool/  
/var/tmp/  
logs/
```

Now the command is executed without errors, but for the server1 it has copied the whole */var* directory, including the folders to be excluded.
Instead nothing in */var* for the others servers.

Comment: "All parameters in this file must be separated by tabs". Do you have maybe a space instead? Also I suggest you use `exclude_file` instead of multiple excludes.

Comment: Please, see my update

Answer (score 1):

You have to separate the arguments to rsync with spaces, not commas. I.e., instead of this:

```
+rsync_long_args=--rsync-path=/usr/local/bin/rsync_wrapper.sh,exclude_file=/etc/rsnapshot.exclude
```

You should use:

```
+rsync_long_args=--rsync-path=/usr/local/bin/rsync_wrapper.sh exclude_file=/etc/rsnapshot.exclude
```

rsnapshot will pass the arguments verbatim to rsync. If you use commas, it will believe everything (`--rsync-path=/usr/local/bin/rsync_wrapper.sh,exclude_file=/etc/rsnapshot.exclude`) is a single one, and won't work. There should be errors in the log file for rsnapshot.

That was my experience, at least. I tried to add one more option to `rsync_long_args` and found rsnapshot ignored me. When I changed the comma for a space it started working. Please, try this and see if it works for you too.

Comment: There are some other errors

Answer (score 0):

Include double dashes from the second exclude onward, and separate with tabs. Like this:

```
backup  server2:/var/   server2/    exclude=/var/cache/ --exclude=/var/lock/ --exclude=/var/log/ --exclude=/var/spool/ --exclude=/var/tmp/
```

Note the missing "--" for the first exclude. It's beyond me why this works, but it does.